# Membership in MVC5 blank project

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-membership

I'm trying to make membership work in asp.net mvc5 blank project. I'm using db first approach for that and have installed `apsnet_regsql` for that. After I've created vs2012 internet app and copied everything from Models, Filters, Controllers and Views as well.

But I faced a problem. When I'm trying to acces in login (or something) it throws an exception:

> An exception of type 'System.ArgumentException' occurred in
>   System.Data.dll but was not handled in user code
>
> Additional information: Unable to find the requested .Net Framework
>   Data Provider.  It may not be installed.

here's my connectionstring:

```
<add name="CSharpAssignmentDbContext" connectionString="metadata=res://*/Model.csdl|res://*/Model.ssdl|res://*/Model.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;data source=GIORGI\SQLEXPRESS;initial catalog=CSharpAssignmentDb;integrated security=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;App=EntityFramework&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
```

at first I had another problem and than I found [here](http://notebookheavy.com/2012/08/22/mvc-4-authentication/)

> Create a file in the root of your web app called _AppStart.cshtml and
>   put this in it:

```
@{
     if (!WebSecurity.Initialized)
    {
        WebSecurity.InitializeDatabaseConnection("DefaultConnection", "UserProfile", "UserId",
                                                 "UserName", autoCreateTables: true);
    }
}
```

What's wrong with it? I'm using latest EF 6.1.3 Db first

Comment: Looks like you need to use NuGet to install the EntityFramework into your web project.

Comment: @TheGeekYouNeed nah it's installed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17220362/entity-framework-data-provider-not-found-entityclient)

> You cannot use that connectionstring for anything else than the edmx
>   connection. The way I have it in my web.config makes the website use
>   that same connectionstring for the membership stuff too, which is not
>   compatible with the System.Data.EntityClient provider and needs the
>   System.Data.Sqlclient in my case. Adding a second connectionstring,
>   minus the Entity Framework stuff in it and having that referenced by
>   the membership provider attributes in the web.config removes all
>   errors and allows the page to render and request stuff from the SQL
>   server.

So I've added second connectionstring

```
<add name="DefaultConnection" connectionString="Data Source=.\SQLExpress;Initial Catalog=CSharpAssignmentDb;Integrated Security=SSPI;" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
```

And it solved my problem